# Flex mobile access android libraries?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- Is it possible, and how ( if it is ) to use functions from Android libraries from Flex mobile application ?

Comment: Functions like what? Camera, Acelerometer?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4aefe03513238d8a1b8-8000.html

Comment: The answer is to create a Native Extension.  @ethrbunny already gave you a link to the docs.  If you Google on Flash Native Extensions android, you'll find plenty of samples, instructions, and probably some ready to go extensions.

Comment: I wanna to access functions which is inside java libraries.
For instance - databases drivers, encription algorithms .. etc..
But not to create them, but access already created and packed by 3rd party providers.

Comment: @BertiKelvin You'll have to include those libraries within your Native Extension library, but you should be able to use them. Just avoid trying to use the native Android MediaPlayer class. It's a nightmare with ANEs. Near impossible, if you don't want to force the user to turn their screen on/off to play the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native extension is the answer, credits to flextras. 
yes, you'll be able to access the java api functions with native extension. because native in android is the java.. sort of.. on iOS you could use it to use objective-c, on windows you can use it for c++..